# Is there a way to check if std::future state is ready in a guaranteed wait-free manner?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, std-future

I know that I can check the state of the `std::future` the following way:

`my_future.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0)) == std::future_status::ready`

But according to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_for) `std::future::wait_for` may block in some cases:

> This function may block for longer than timeout_duration due to scheduling or resource contention delays.

Is it still the case when `timeout_duration` is 0 ? If so, is there another way to query the state in a guaranteed wait-free manner ?

Comment: What does your code intend to do if it is not ready?

Comment: i dont think you can get any faster than 0 + scheduling and resource contention delays

Comment: C++ only specifies what the observable effects of the code are. Absence of blocking or waiting is not an observable effect.

Comment: Do you expect `x+=1;` where `x` is an `int` to be guaranteed wait-free?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [quote from cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_for) is simply there to remind you that the OS scheduler is a factor here and that other tasks requiring platform resources could be using the CPU-time your thread needs in order to return from `wait_for()` -- regardless of the specified timeout duration being zero or not. That's all. You cannot technically be guaranteed to get more than that on a non-realtime platform. As such, the C++ Standard says nothing about this, but you can see other interesting stuff there -- see the paragraph for `wait_for()` under [[futures.unique_future¶21]](http://eel.is/c++draft/futures#unique_future-21):

> Effects: None if the shared state contains a deferred function
>   ([futures.async]), otherwise **blocks until the shared state is ready or
>   until the relative timeout ([thread.req.timing]) specified by
>   `rel_­time` has expired.**

No such mention of the additional delay here, **but it does say that you *are* blocked,** and it remains implementation dependent whether `wait_for()` is [`yield()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/yield)ing the thread<sup>1</sup> first thing upon such blocking or immediately returning if the timeout duration is zero. In addition, it might also be necessary for an implementation to synchronize access to the future's status in a locking manner, which would have to be applied prior to checking if a potential immediate return is to take place. Hence, **you don't even have the guarantee for [*lock-freedom*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm#Lock-freedom) here, let alone *wait-freedom*.**

Note that the same applies for calling [`wait_until`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_until) with a time in the past.

> Is it still the case when timeout_duration is 0 ? If so, is there
>   another way to query the state in a guaranteed wait-free manner ?

So yes, implementation of `wait_free()` notwithstanding, this is *still the case*. As such, this is the closest to *wait-free* you're going to get for checking the state.

---

<sup>1</sup> In simple terms, this means "releasing" the CPU and putting your thread at the back of the scheduler's queue, giving other threads some CPU-time.

Comment: I'm wondering if the overhead is roughly equivalent to reading the `std::atomic<bool>` (ready) flag ?

Comment: @AlexandreA. That is not an easy question to answer without precise measurements. Even if your `atomic` returns `true` for `is_lock_free()`, the atomic operation on your processor is something that should be timed and compared against given implementation of `std::future` queries.

Comment: @AlexandreA. Having said that, note that [`std::atmoic_flag`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag) is "*[...] guaranteed to be lock-free.*" : )

Comment: Interesting remark about `std::atomic_flag` thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

To answer your second question, there is currently no way to check if the future is ready other than waiting.  We will likely get this at some point: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/future/is_ready.  If your runtime library supports the concurrency extensions and you don't mind using `experimental` in your code, then you can use `is_ready()` now.  That being said, I know of few cases where you must check a future's state.  Are you sure it's necessary?

Comment: There's no guarantee that `is_ready()` does anything other than `wait_for(0s) == future_status::ready`, so it's more readable and more expressive, but is not necessarily wait-free.

Comment: I would not expect `is_ready()` to behave that way, but it's really a quality of implementation issue.  In any case, `is_ready()` is the best you can do.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it still the case when timeout_duration is 0 ?

Yes. That's true for **any** operation. The OS scheduler could pause the thread (or the whole process) to allow another thread to run on the same CPU.

> If so, is there another way to query the state in a guaranteed wait-free manner ?

No. Using a zero timeout is the correct way.

There's not even a guarantee that the shared state of a `std::future` doesn't lock a mutex to check if it's ready, so it would be impossible to guarantee it was wait-free.

For GCC's implementation the ready flag is an atomic so there's no mutex lock needed, and if it's ready then `wait_for` returns immediately. If it's not ready then there are some more atomic operations and then a check to see if the timeout has passed already, then a system call. So for a zero timeout there are just some atomic loads and function calls (no system call).